# Determine the class of this system of partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $V(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are maps from $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, in which $\phi(x)$ is an auxiliary function.

Could anyone help me to classify this system of partial differential equations (It is called Zubov's equation)?

$$\nabla V(x)\cdot f(x)=\phi(x)(1-V(x))$$

My thought is that

(1) It is a first order pde system Is that correct?

(2) It is linear pde system. Is that correct?

(3) Is it an Elliptic or Hyperbolic or and Parabolic PDE?

(4) Is it a Haminton-Jabobi equation?

(5) Do you see other aspects of the system?

(6) how to solve this system?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its first order linear. Use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). As $\phi$ is an auxillary function I doubt you'll be able to explicitly determine the solution.

Comment: @mattos Yes, usually we need to first assume $\phi$ to be a specific function, and then solve the equation..